# AWS SecretManager Read and Write concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

AWS SecretManager Read and Write concurrency.

If I am writing new secret value to a secret and if at the same time read is performed,
does the read call waits for he write calls to complete?

Or read will retrieve some invalid or intermediate value of the keys stored inside the secret?

Comment: Maurice is correct. Update to Secrets Manager are atomic (though [eventually consistent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/troubleshoot.html#troubleshoot_general_eventual-consistency)) . You will not see partial updates and the read calls will not block on the writes.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `GetSecretValue` [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html) returns the version of the secret that has the `AWSCURRENT` stage. It also allows you to fetch older versions of a secret by specifying the VersionId. Versions are also immutable and if you call [`PutSecretValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_PutSecretValue.html) you create a new version.

You won't get partial versions here - the label `AWSCURRENT` will only be switched to the new version once the update is complete. Everything else would result in a terrible user experience.